# How to add checkboxes in filters

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, json

I have a jQuery data table individual column searching. I want a select list with checkboxes in each column, which would be driving the filtering options, something visually like what ColVis does (http://datatables.net/extras/colvis).

I tried to bind a jQuery event handler to the checkbox and call fnFilter() with the required filtering parameters on the table, but I can't do it. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../test/SiteAssets/jqueryy-
3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables
.jqueryui.min.css">  
<script type="text/javascript" 
src=".../test/SiteAssets/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
</head>  
 <script>

 function loadMyItems() {  
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;  
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + 
"/Testing/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test123')/items?
$select=FirstName,Title,JobTitle,Company,WorkPhone,Email";  
$.ajax({  
    url: oDataUrl,  
    type: "GET",  
    dataType: "json",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
    },  
    success: mySuccHandler,  
    error: myErrHandler  
});  
}  

 </script>

<body>  
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
    <thead>  
        <tr>  
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>  
            <th>JobTitle</th>  
            <th>Company</th>  
            <th>Business Phone</th>  
            <th width="18%">Email</th>                
        </tr>  
    </thead>  
     <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>JobTitle</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Business Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot> 
</table>   
</body>  
</html>  
<script>

function mySuccHandler(data) {  
try {  
    var dataTableExample = $('#example').DataTable();  
    if (dataTableExample != 'undefined') {  
        dataTableExample.destroy();  
    }  
    dataTableExample = $('#example').DataTable({  
        scrollY: 300,  
        "aaData": data.d.results,  
        "aoColumns": [{  
            "mData": "FirstName"  
        }, {  
            "mData": "Title"  
        }, {  
            "mData": "JobTitle"  
        }, {  
            "mData": "Company"  
        }, {  
            "mData": "WorkPhone"  
        }, {  
            "mData": "Email"  

        }]  
    });  
    } catch (e) {  
    alert(e.message);  
    }  

dataTableExample.columns().every( function () {
var that = this;

$( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
    that
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
}
} );
} );
}  

function myErrHandler(data, errCode, errMessage) {  
alert("Error: " + errMessage);  
}  

$(document).ready(function() {  
loadMyItems();  

// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
    } );
} );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no select with checkboxes control in HTML 
you'll have to create your own Checkbox list and use CSS to manage its visibility.

here's an example:

[How to create checkbox inside dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206919/how-to-create-checkbox-inside-dropdown)

for the filtering i'll recommend you to add a class, tag , id or other selector to the results of each row so you can filter your results.